# How to get Windows region format?

Tags: c#, format, culture, region

In the control panel of Windows there is a combobox where  we can change the regional format (controlPanel => Region => Formats (windows 10)). For example Persian or English

I want to retrieve this regional setting in my application.

I tried code like this:

```
        CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
        var installed = ci.Name;

        ci = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        var currentUi = ci.Name;

        ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var current = ci.Name;
```

but `installed` and `currentUi` are always 'en-US' and `current` is 'fa-IR'

and when I change the format in the control panel they don't change.

Comment: Isn't `fa-IR` the one you where expecting? Besides have you tried: `start application => check culture => change region format => restart application and check again`? I think it only changes after you restart the application.

Comment: i restart my app but it does not change

Comment: The control panel applet lets you change formats for a region that is not the current region.  Not actually very useful, is it?  Still, it is necessary to configure the formats when a program changes its default culture.  Nothing in the snippet suggest that you are doing this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this code.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
var thread = new Thread(s => ((State)s).Result = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
var state = new State();
thread.Start(state);
thread.Join();
var culture = state.Result;
```

And then we use `culture.Name`.
And in this case it's not necessary to close and reopen the program.